# BeautifulSoup Tag Removal unexpected result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I wrote some code to extract only what's within the `<p>` tags of some HTML code.  Here is my code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_string, 'html')
no_tags=' '.join(el.string for el in soup.find_all('p', text=True))
```

It works how I want it to for most of the examples it is run on, but I have noticed that in examples such as

```
<p>hello, how are you <code>other code</code> my name is joe</p>
```

it returns nothing.  I suppose this is because there are other tags within the `<p>` tags.  So just to be clear, what I would want it to return is

```
hello, how are you my name is joe
```

That is, I want everything inside the `<p>` tags but only the first level in.  I would like to ignore everything that is enclosed in other tags within the `<p>` tags.
can someone help me out regarding how to deal with such examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think that you can use it to extract the text which is within p tag.

```
my_string = "<p>hello, how are you <code>other code</code> my name is joe</p>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(my_string, 'html')

soup.code.extract()
text = soup.p.get_text()
print text
```

Comment: Its working for the example but when I run it on some others I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extract' I'm not sure why though

Comment: It will not work if tag 'code' doesn't exist. When you use soup.X.extract() you remove X tag from the object so if it isn't there you will get an error.

Comment: ok, is there a way to check if code is there before it is run?

Comment: If you use soup.p.findChild('code') it will return the tag 'code', so you can use it to know if it is there. But if tag 'code' isn't there it will return a empty value(False). if soup.p.findChild("code"): Do something

Comment: now I am getting the error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findChild' which I suppose means that p doesn't exist in some example.  Now I need a way to check if p is there :(

Comment: It works for me. Can you put your source code as an answer? I want to see if something is wrong, maybe we can fix it more quickly :).

Comment: Yes it works for the above example, except in other examples I have there are no <p> tags.  In that case it doesn't seem to work/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37587/discussion-between-ricardo-and-user1893354)